# Proving an entropy inequality

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I am given that $Z$ is independent of $(X,U)$, where $Z$ and $X$ are binary random variables while $U$ is an arbitrary random variable. I need to prove the following:
$$ H(X\oplus Z|U) \geq H(X|U)$$
Am I doing this right?:
$$ H(X\oplus Z|U) - H(X\oplus Z|U,Z) + H(X\oplus Z|U,Z) - H(X|U)$$
$$ H(X\oplus Z|U) - H(X\oplus Z|U,Z) + H(X|U,Z) - H(X|U)$$
$$ H(X\oplus Z|U) - H(X\oplus Z|U,Z) + H(X|U) - H(X|U)$$
$$ I(X\oplus Z;Z|U) \geq 0$$
I manipulate the intial expression. I am not very confident about the proof. Can someone verify?

Comment: Check your expressions again. Should you been only having - and + in the first 3 lines? No inequalities or equivalences?

Comment: @auspicious99 I was just playing with an expression. All 4 are equivalent, in the last line I could conclude that the expression is $\geq$ 0, which would then apply to the above 3 expressions as well. Sorry for the poor writing!

Comment: @D.W. Yea, but I can't see how that helps!

Comment: You're right, never mind my comment.  Can you prove $H(X\oplus Z) \ge H(X)$?  That might be easier to think about.

Comment: @D.W. I am thinking along the same line, write $H(X)$ as $H(X\oplus Z|Z)$, it is clear then.